Problem with graphicx in Anki
I am trying to include an image using graphicx in Anki, here's my code:
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\special{papersize=3in,5in}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,tikz-cd,graphicx}
\graphicspath{{C:/Users/USER/Desktop/}}
\pagestyle{empty}
\setlength{\parindent}{0in}
\begin{document}

Rest of my flashcard
$$\includegraphics[bb=0 0 30 60]{Capture.png}$$

\end{document}

And here is the output:

I've looked through everything relevant to this on stack exchange but haven't been able to find a solution. The error given in my case is
LaTeX Warning: File `C:/Users/USER/Desktop/Capture.png' not found on input line 11
But the code still renders, just with a placeholder image.
How do I solve this?
P.S.: I am not in draft mode, I've tried png, jpg, svg, bmp, all yield the same results. I have also executed the exact same code in TeXworks and TeXmaker, it works in both cases.

How do you save Capture.png? How does this code do it? Don't see it. // Why don't you just: a) create a drawing using class standalone, b) convert it into a bitmap format (there are many ways to do it including freeware imageMagick), c) load that result into Anki? I.e. why do you need Latex code inside Anki for a standard job??

I make all my Anki flashcards with Latex, and I wanted to have an image in one of them, which is why I ended up trying to do this. I don't understand what the probelm is, since the exact same code works both in TeXworks and TeXmaker, and the image is saved on my desktop. It's baffling to me that it doesn't work in Anki though, since I don't understand why there's a difference in the way Anki compiles things and the way my other programs do it.

Well, try standing in our shoes. You posted some code, but the whole workflow you use, is missing. So, how should we be able to reproduce your problem, less a solution? // All I can do is to suggest a systematic approach how you, and you alone, can localize the problem: A) Take the last file that worked this way, i.e. made it into Anki. B) copy it and very gradually rework it, step-by-step, into sth. similar to what you posted. C) recognize the difference(s) once it succeeds or fails the same way. D) work from there.

How is your Anki configured to use LaTeX? This Q+A suggests that Anki may have a workflow that compiles to dvi and then converts to png. This would not work with the graphics types you tried. You can however make it use pdflatex instead (see linked post).
